# How can i add more searchable options to React-Select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

So what i need to do is have the search form of react-select not only react to id an value, but i also want it to be able to search for synonyms of the select options.

For example in a unit of measures list:

```
{
"id": "MIN",
"name": "minute",
"synonym": "time"
}
```

I want to be able to type in "min", "minute" or "time" and end up with the selection "minute".

I tried it with pushing another element into the array:

```
mapUnitOfMeasure()
{
    const results = [ ];
    for(const c of measureUnits)
        results.push({ value : c.id, label : c.name, syn: c.synonym });
    }
    return results
}
```

In my render method, the select element looks like this:

```
<Select
                className="react-select"
                placeholder=""
                disabled={this.state.disabled}
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                onBlur={this.handleBlur.bind(this)}
                searchable={true}
                clearable={true}
                multi={false}
                noResultsText={i18n.getMessage('CurrencyInput.search.form.noResults')}
                options={this.mapUnitOfMeasure()} />
        )
```

But "syn" never reacts to a search query.

Anyone have an idea how i can make it work?

Comment: Just to be sure, you're using react-select v1 right ?

Comment: i thought we are using version 2, but i just noticed we use 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `filterOptions` props that allows you to create your own filter function.

By default it works like this:

```
filterOptions={(options, filter, currentValues) => {
  // Do no filtering, just return all options
  return options;
}}
```

If you want to make a search in `label` and `syn` you can use the function like this:

```
filterOptions = (options, filterString, values) => {
  return options.filter(
    x => x.synonym.includes(filterString) || x.label.includes(filterString)
  );
};
```

**WARNING**

Using `filterOptions` will override `filterOption`, `matchPos`, `matchProp`, `ignoreCase` and `ignoreAccents` options. You will have to take care of those props by yourself.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/81q12ozp2l) a live example.

Comment: i found out that you can search for all values if you do the return like this: 

    `return item.symbol && item.syn.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1 ||
                item.label && item.label.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1 ||
                item.value && item.value.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1`

(apparently i cant manage to format code the right way in here...)

Comment: Is this answer required any specific verison?

Comment: Question has been asked for V1.1.0