# React-select onchange event multiple proprieties

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

Here is my question/problem. using the current version of #react-select, on-change, the event contains the value and the label. But how can I set it to return some more props? For example, I am selecting a zip code, but I want it to return the city and the calling code for that city. I do have that information in the options array for the #react-select

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem and show some code that you tried?

Comment: Can you please share relevant code for better reception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i add more searchable options to React-Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201317/how-can-i-add-more-searchable-options-to-react-select)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @steve-cutter-blades for your comment, that is correct so i will update my answer:

**UPDATE 20-12-2019**

The onChange function return the full optionObject from the options you pass as prop. So all the keys in each option will be returned:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Select from "react-select";

class App extends Component {

  onChange = (option) => {
    // option.value     -->  "chocolate"
    // option.label     -->  "Chocolate"
    // option.extraInfo -->  "A"
    return option;
  };

  render() {
    const options = [
      { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate", extraInfo: "A" },
      { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry", extraInfo: "B" },
      { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla", extraInfo: "C" }
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          options={options}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          isMulti={false}
          closeMenuOnSelect={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

My previous answer worked, but was a bad work around.

Comment: Thanks , @stephan-hovius. You helped me a lot.

Comment: no problem! :D If you have more questions, feel free to ask them :)

Comment: Wait, I don't understand. If the information you're looking for is already attached to the 'option' that you selected, then that info is included in the 'option' passed to your onChange handler. React-select doesn't filter out any keys, but passes the entire object, regardless of what was the label/value. (at least in the current build anyway)

Comment: Updated the answer. I can't believe i answered that workaround. I guess I wasn't experienced with react-select enough... Thanks for noticing @Steve -Cutter- Blades